# Unable to start iisexpress

Tags: iis-10

```
run c:\program files\IIS Express\iisexpress /trace:error
```

output:

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 1597465
W3 Server initializing WinSock. CTC = 1597481
W3 Server WinSock initialized. CTC = 1597481
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled). CTC = 1597481
Start listenerChannel http:0
Error (rc=80070422) in UlInitialize. Exiting
Error initializing ULATQ. hr = 80070422
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable to start iisexpress.
```

I'm using Windows 7, IISExpress 10, tried reinstall, still didn't work.
Can someone help? thanks.

Comment: finally know that it is because that my machine has http service been disabled by the setting in the registry